# MobileNetV2 in Keras: Adjusting depth

Tags: keras, image-segmentation

I am trying to reconstruct specific U-Net architecture with the MobileNetV2 backbone using Keras. [It seems](https://keras.io/api/applications/mobilenet/#mobilenetv2-function) for MobilenetV1, there is a way to adjust the depth using the `depth_multiplier` argument, while no such thing is available for MobileNetV2. I need to increase the default depth and the number of skip connections in the U-Net. Is there a simple way to solve this using the Keras layers' MobileNetV2 without building it from scratch?